# Tkinter CSV store/write

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having so much trouble with the actual completion of this code, I would like to implement a few more features such as searching a csv file to find data, and implement some type data validation into this which I am having a lot of trouble with. Initially the program was just meant to

1. Have a GUI
2. Read/return results
3. Write to file.

All I have seem to have got thus far is step 3, write.

```
from tkinter import *
import csv

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.output()

    def output(self):
        Label(text='New homework:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.e = Entry(root, width=20)
        self.e.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.writeToFile)
        self.b.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=5,pady=5)

    def writeToFile(self):
        with open('dates.csv', 'a') as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, storing=csv.STORE_ALL)
            w.writerow([self.e.get()])

        self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.writeToFile)
        self.b.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=5,pady=5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    root.title('Jacksons Software Journal')
    root.geometry('400x400')
    app=App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please just copy and paste all that code/text from your text editor directly into your question's text, thanks.

Comment: @downshift http://pastebin.com/M2eW3Vvz here  is a pastebin link due to the erros I am receiving trying to paste it.

Comment: @downshift thank you for the help

Comment: You should ask some specific question, see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)